# Prevent HTTPS Access to Website by IP in Nginx

Tags: web-services, nginx, web, https, webserver

I've completed setting up a webserver using Nginx on Ubuntu 16.04 through AWS. All HTTP traffic is redirected to HTTPS for the registered domain and subdomains. And when someone types "http://IP_Address", they are bounced to the default HTTPS page.

It's all pretty slick except for one thing... if a user types "https://IP_Address", they get a page saying "The owner of IP_Adderess has configured their website improperly. To protect your information from being stolen..."

I've tried redirecting from a server block with "server_name _;" and the message is that the certificate is for the wrong site. So I created a self-signed cert just for the redirect server block. But of course it now gives a slightly different "not trusted" message and continues to offer to help users get my site blocked.

I have also tried telling it to just return 404, but it appears the check for whether the site is valid or not happens before it gets to that point. Is there any way to simply cause "https:// IP_Address" to return a 404 error or just not respond to URLs I don't want to serve from?

My config (with edits for brevity) is:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://example.org$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    root /var/www/example.org/html;
    index index.html index.php;
    server_name example.org www.example.org;

    location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    <SSL stuff, turning off gzip, transport headers, etc.>

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /var/www/nginx/html;
    }
    server {
    listen 443 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 default_server;
    server_name _;

    ssl_certificate     <path to cert>;
    ssl_certificate_key <path to key>;

    return 301 https://example.org$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 default_server;
    server_name _;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx-selfsigned.key;

    return 301 https://visionsforlearning.org$request_uri;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Having experimented further with this, I believe the answer would be in configuring Nginx to simply not respond to the initial handshake request for invalid domains. Once the handshake attempt is acknowledged, anything less than success is interpreted by modern browsers as a server config issue with potentially malicious intent.

The trick then, which I am not sure is supported by Nginx, is to listen on port 443 for contact from valid domains and subdomains, while not listening/ignoring invalid ones.

Use of "deny all" does not resolve this, because the SSL handshake occurs first.